# Scroll não funciona após append com jquery

Tags: php, jquery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Bom, eu estou pegando posts quando carrega a pagina, porem quando eu faço um novo post e dou um append ele vai para o final da pagina e tambem ele fica pela metade o scroll nao acompanha, eu tentei de tudo com jquery mas n rola :/

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, obg e boa noite..

```
//Pega o post no bd
$lastpost = DBRead( 'posts', "WHERE id = '". $id ."'", 'conteudo');
//Transforma o array em string
$postcont = (string)$lastpost[0]['conteudo'];
// esta função e de um outro script apenas para cercar o conteudo que veio
// do banco com html estilizado
$post = post($postcont);
// aqui eu dou o append para colocar o post no feed
echo "<script>$('div.overview').append(".$post.");</script>";
```

Comment: Pela imagem, está usando google chrome. Nesse mesmo browser, pressione CTRL+SHIFT+I para abrir o console. No console vc poderá ver quais erros acontecem.

Comment: não aponta nenhum erro, nem mesmo com o firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu `div.overview` não está mudando de tamanho, por isso o scroll não "funciona".

Imagine que seu `div.overview` possui 400px de altura, e vc faz o `.append()` de um objeto que, renderizado, terá 600px de altura. Ele não, obrigatoriamente, irá expandir seu `div` de container.

O resultado será como o seu, um `div` container com uma altura fixa, e um conteúdo maior que não será exibido - ou até será, mas irá "vazar" os limites do `div`. Mas como o `div.overview` é o container, o scrool vai obedecer à suas medidas, e não tendo necessidade de "scrollar", não irá fazer.

Espero que eu tenha ajudado, e não confundido mais. :)

Comment: Muito obrigado! agora vou tentar mudar o tamanho do overview.. eu tinha até tentado mas nao pensei que esse poderia ser a causa do problema.. Estou usando o material design lite e um template do mesmo, vou recomeçar o layout do zero e me atentar aos detalhes.